# pandas read_csv keep quote for specific column

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a csv called `file.csv` in the following format:

```
"hash";"timeStamp";"protocol";"type";"subTransactions";"gas";"contract"
"0x48e306ab695e5ertretreter269baf6342325e8d952b2305875";"1619023543";"";"";"[{"type":"outgoing","symbol":"MATIC","amount":896.0375,"address":"0x7d1afa7erw324abc0cfc608aacfebb0"}]";"0.019060399";"0x401f6c983ea2343f84d70b31c151321188b"
"0xd22b9622510a94b926456546aeb7ea1880fcf7c8fd9902c8b9c3771beb";"1619023794";"";"";"[{"type":"incoming","symbol":"MATIC","amount":296.0375,"address":"0x7d1afa7b718fb89werwefc608aacfebb0"}]";"0.00913276";"0xe93381fb4c4f14bwrer305d799241a"
```

I parse the csv with the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";")
```

This results in the following:

```
hash                                               timeStamp        protocol  type                                    subTransactions       gas                               contract
0x48e306ab695e5ertretreter269baf6342325e8d952b...  1619023543       NaN   NaN  [{type":"outgoing","symbol":"MATIC","amount":8...  0.019060  0x401f6c983ea2343f84d70b31c151321188b
0xd22b9622510a94b926456546aeb7ea1880fcf7c8fd99...  1619023794       NaN   NaN  [{type":"incoming","symbol":"MATIC","amount":2...  0.009133       0xe93381fb4c4f14bwrer305d799241a
```

The problem I face is the values in the column `subTransactions`. Instead of `[{type":"outgoing","symbo...` it should be `[{"type":"outgoing","symbo...`. Ie. a double-quote is missing in front of type. I have tried to fix it with replace but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data are not quite clean ... In this particular case you can use a workaround like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json 

def _conv(s):
    s = s.replace('[{type":', '[{"type":')
    return json.loads(s[:-1])

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";", converters={'subTransactions': _conv})
print(df)
```

NB: this is not a generic solution!